# Html Validation error in Asp.Net form

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an Asp.Net website which is throwing up a W3C validation error on the form element

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
```

I'm using the web forms routing option, so the home page is blank, as you see in the above example.

However, I'm getting a validation error, detailed below:

```
 Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty.
```

As I have no control of this I wondered how its possible to work round the issue, if at all. I can't imagine that every Asp.Net site in the world is broken.

*** UPDATE ***

Guys you're missing the point. The error relates to the action attribute being blank, but this is being rendered this way because the page name is actually blank. Its blank because I'm using url routing.

Comment: Can I see link which you are trying to validated in w3c. I have to look into it and need some changes.

Comment: Don't feel like you need 100% validation. Use it to check for unintended errors and real problems. This is neither, from what you've said... so forget about it

Answer (score 0):

just try using the "form" tag like this

```
<form method="post" action="" runat="server" id="form">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP.Net website, there should be a main form like the below

```
<asp:Form runat="server" id="form1">
</asp:Form>
```

This will be rendered HTML

```
<form id="aspnet_Form" action="pagename.aspx">
</form>
```

But your code looks like, you removed the asp.net form and created your own form with out action attribute.

To submit any form you need to specify `valid action attribute value`. But it is missing in your code. Please speciffy `action="somepage.aspx"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="your page" runat="server" id="form">
```

You can clearly get the answer from your error message that something should be there in `action` of `form` .

Answer (score 0):

I just add something like this in the codebehind:

```
this.Form.Action = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
```

Comment: Could you reword your question and maybe add a bit more of an explanation? -- I don't quite follow you.